# Update xDoc with same element name with No attributes

Tags: c#, .net, xml

My XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <Properties>
   <Ranges>
    <GridRange>
     <ColumnID>991</ColumnID>
     <LowerBound>30</LowerBound>
     <UpperBound>59</UpperBound>
    </GridRange>
    <GridRange>
     <ColumnID>991</ColumnID>
     <LowerBound>60</LowerBound>
     <UpperBound />
    </GridRange>
   </Ranges>
 </Properties>
```

I want to update the value of the element  (when it is 991) within  to 1000. My code updating only the first  to 1000 and not the second one.

```
 XElement columnID = xProperty.Root.Elements("Ranges").Elements("GridRange").Elements("ColumnID").FirstOrDefault();
 if (null != columnID && Convert.ToInt64(columnID.Value) == 991)  
    columnID.Value = "1000";
```

But I want both ColumnID element value to be 1000. How do i achieve this.

Comment: Yes, you have call to `.FirstOrDefault()`... Have you tried to remove it and update all elements in the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the code below to iterate through all `GridRange` elements and evaluate the `ColumnID` element's value.

```
Int64 columnID = Int64.MinValue;
foreach (var xElem in xProperty.Descendants("GridRange"))
{
    columnID = Int64.MinValue;
    var elem = xElem.Element("ColumnID");
    if (elem == null || !Int64.TryParse(elem.Value, out columnID) || columnID != 991)
        continue;
    elem.Value = "1000"; 
}
```

Now are you sure you need an `Int64` as opposed to a `Int32`? Are the `ColumnID` values likely to exceed `2,147,483,647`?

**EDIT - Without conversions**

If there is no need for conversions this code gets really easy and shorted.

```
foreach (var xElem in xProperty.Descendants("GridRange").Elements("ColumnID").Where(x => x.Value.Equals("991")))
            xElem.Value = "1000";
```

Comment: The value is simply a string; no need to cast to an int(32/64). Just check to see if the value of the element == "991".

Comment: @MetroSmurf just followed the OP's original question. Not sure why they wanted to convert anyway.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're using `FirstOrDefault`. For achieving what you want, do as follows:

```
xDoc.Root.Elements("Ranges")
         .Elements("GridRange")
         .Elements("ColumnID")
         .Where(xe => xe.Value == "991")
         .ToList()
         .ForEach(el => el.Value = "1000");
```